# How to achive the cross domain single sign-on

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, single-sign-on, google-account, multiple-domains

How to keep maintain cookies and session across 3 different domain?

I am setting up a centralized authentication for our 3 products which has different domain, like abc.com, xyz.com and def.com. so i have created a login server like login.abc.com, where my centerlized login will occur. so whenever a user entered abc.com and login himself in login.abc.com, then he can access all 3 products, but the challenging is when he opens third products or second products how can i authenticate him? because it's in different domain and same cookies doesn't work in different domains. So if you have any idea to overcome from this problem, then please share your ideas.

how to store cookies or JWT token, so that other site can take that cookies/ token for validating with user

Note: Like google, if you signed-in in gmail, then you automatically logged-in in youtube, though they have different domain.

i want such architecture like google follows.

Comment: This question seems like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837067/how-does-google-achieve-single-sign-onwith-third-party-cookies-disabled

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign on (SSO) is a user experience that a user signs in only one time. A user is automatically signed into other applications if the user has already signed into one application. The user's authentication session is maintained by the dedicated and centralized SSO service. In your example, the abc.com will remember user sign-in status, if user has been signed in to abc.com, user does not prompt for sign-in again whenever user tries to access applications in any other domain.